# Describe the graph for the following equation $(x^2)(x+y+1)=(y^2)(x+y+1)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> Describe the graph for the following equation $(x^2)(x+y+1)=(y^2)(x+y+1)$.

This is quite straight forward. There is simply an equation with two variables and standard notation is assumed.

Comment: Subtract left side from both sides, factor out like terms, factor difference of two squares to get $(y+x)(y-x)(y+x+1)=0$, note that a product is zero if and only if at least one factor is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$ab = cb \implies (a-c)b = 0 \implies [(a-c = 0) \vee (b = 0)].$

Similarly, $(x^2 - y^2)(x + y + 1) = 0 \implies 
[(x^2 - y^2 = 0) \vee (x + y + 1 = 0)].$

$x^2 = y^2 \implies [(x = y) \vee (x = -y)].$

So, you have $(3)$ lines.

Answer (score 0):

If $x+y+1\ne0$ we divide both sides by it getting (green lines)

$$x^2-y^2=0$$

which is a conic section, a pair of straight lines.

If $x+y+1=0$ the graph can include it (red line) in the total picture of *three factors* and three lines representing them:

$$ x+y+1=0,\; x=y,\; x=-y.\;$$

[image]